If $T$ has finite dimensional range so does $T^*$
This is 4th problem from section 10A from Axler's Measure, Integration
& Real Analysis

Suppose $V$ and $W$ are Hilbert spaces and $T \in \mathcal{B}(V, W)$ has finite-dimensional range. Prove that $T^*$ also has finite-dimensional range.

I have no idea how to approach this problem. I tried to play with the definition of adjoint and I tried using formulas relating ranges and kernels of $T$ and $T^*$, however I was not able to solve this problem.
Could you please provide me some hints on how can I approach this problem. Thanks.

Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/717604/does-a-clean-proof-exist-of-why-mbox-dim-ranget-mbox-dim-ranget and of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/898648/dimension-of-the-range-of-an-operator-and-its-adjoint and of  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2515153/let-e-and-f-banach-spaces-and-t-in-le-f-if-dim-rt-infty-then and ... shall I continue? Please use site search and approach0.

More prosaically, since $T$ has finite range, it can be written as the (finite) sum $Tv = \sum_k \langle \tau_k, v \rangle w_k$ where $\tau_k \in V$, and the $w_k \in W$ form a basis for the range. By definition
$\langle w , Tv \rangle = \langle T^*w , v \rangle $, and so

 $ \langle w , Tv \rangle = \sum_k\langle w ,  w_k \rangle \langle \tau_k, v \rangle = \left\langle \sum_k\langle w_k , w \rangle \tau_k, v\right\rangle $. In particular $T^*w = \sum_k\langle w_k , w \rangle \tau_k$.


Please don't answer duplicate questions. See here.

I get that, but the OP was asking how to approach the problem, and while the other answers are succinct, a more 'explicit' approach seemed to address the OP's question.

Really not getting the lemming downvoting.
